# DMZ to LAN. SMB Print and File Sharing not working

Tags: tcp, dmz, smb, lan

I have a Windows Server 2008 r2 machine on DMZ.  We have a shared folder on there that one day a couple weeks ago was no longer able to be accessed.  No changes occurred except for maybe windows updates.  I am having an issue trying to map the shared drive on the dmz server from any internal LAN machine.

Steps I have tried so far:

1. Completely turned off firewall.
2. Made sure all services that pertain to print and file sharing are on turned on and running.
3. Ensured that the checkbox for File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks is checked.
4. Turned on File and Printer sharing, network discovery, and public sharing folder in Advanced sharing settings.
5. Tried uninstalling File and Printer sharing driver and reinstalled.
6. Verified that some local security policy were turned on to make sure to allow file and printer sharing.
7. Ran packet traces on Cisco ASA firewall with Cisco tech support but they are claiming that the packets are being allowed through without issue.  They're saying that the smb ports (445, 137-139) on the DMZ server are not responding once the packets get into the DMZ server.
8. Went through registry and made sure everything for SMB1 and SMB2 were turned on.

I am able to remote the DMZ server and ping it from any LAN machine but not able to map the shared drive.  I am at a loss and have been pulling my hair out.  If anyone could lend a hand and assist with this or lend some recommendations to me, that would be awesome and very appreciated.  One last thing, I read a lot about the wannacry ransomware attack and apparently a lot of this could be dealing with a patch that may have come out that disallows this.  Could this be true judging by the steps I have taken already in my troubleshooting?

Comment: this is not a security question

Comment: Think this should be moved as it's not IS related. But to help are you able to connect to the machine via \\localip ? If so can you connect to the admin shares? \\localip\e$?

Comment: I am not.  The only way i can connect to the dmz machine is to ping it or remote desktop to it.  When I try to do as you suggested above, I cannot.  I am on a domain LAN network machine trying to use \\172.*.*.* in a file explorer but am getting errors.  When i try to map it using different credentials being that the dmz machine is not on the domain, it still doesn't work. @ISMSDEV

Comment: @ISMSDEV I attempted a telnet "IP" 445 and it's blocked.  I tried 3389 and that worked.  But what's weird, is the dmz servers firewall is completely off and like i mentioned in the post, Cisco support did logging and they said the asa firewall is NOT blocking those smb ports.  I don't know what else to do.  Pulling my hair out!  lol.

Comment: @schroeder do you know of anything that this could be?